# I need to display a certain row from a file

Tags: java, readline

i need to get text from selected line from Txt file and print it on JLabel object
I am learning Java and I do not have anyone who can help me with this code, thank everyone who will help

if you need more code from my project, I can send it

```
public int check(String filename, String str)
    {
        int row=0;
        try{
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(filename);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
        while(br.ready())
        {
            if(br.readLine().equals(str))
            {
               br.close();
               return row;

            }
            row=row+1;
        }
        br.close();
        return -1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error");
        }
        return -1;
    } 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    String str=jComboBoxAdminPUsers.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println(str);
   int a=check("Pass.txt", str);
   int b=check("Email.txt", str);
   try{
   FileReader fr=new FileReader("Pass.txt");
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
   String pass="";
   for (int i=0;i<=a;i++)
         pass=br.readLine();
   jLabelPassword.setText(pass);
      br.close();

   FileReader fr1=new FileReader("Email.txt");
   BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(fr1);
   String email="";
   for (int i=0;i<=b;i++)
         email=br1.readLine();
   jLabelEmail.setText(email);
      br1.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {

   }
```

Comment: use regex pattern matching and substring here to fetch specific text

Comment: As you are at the beginning of learning journey, I would recommend you to forget `Swing` and start to learn `JavaFX`. `Swing` is a deprecated GUI technology. In addition can you provide a real world example of how do you define a selected line(text)?

Comment: this is the problem, I don’t know how to select a line

Comment: @mishka12341234 read them all, and use a counter.

Comment: i don't know how to read all and i do not know how to count this